# how do I reuse a tag which was misused previously and nominated for closing?

Tags: support, tags

There was a tag (for example: [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow)) which was misused and that tag was nominated for closing, now I found an interesting library named `flow` (for example) how do I reuse this tag

Comment: resurrecting the tag carries a risk of attracting same troublesome content that led to its removal. Because of that, first thing I'd consider would be to find a better, more detailed name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use it. Assuming its not *actively* being burninated, you shouldn't run into any trouble. If it is, post an answer on that thread indicating the valid usage.

You could also use a slightly different tag to dis-ambiguate it, like [flow-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow-library)

Comment: If the tag was black listed (I doubt flow was) then you have to find another name or ask a mod to assist.  Can't remember if they can circumvent the black list or remove it themselves, but at a minimum, they can get an SE employee to handle it

Comment: @psubsee2003 True, but that list is pretty short.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Also, those few blacklisted tags are a really bad dea for re-using for anything, as they were blacklisted for being excellent crap-attractors without any redeeming value. For standard-burninated tags, it's not quote as bad.

Comment: @Deduplicator agreed, just mentioning it for completeness sake